# Vector space of bidirectional sequences indexed by $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am trying to claim the following:

Consider the vector space of all $(x_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ ($x_i \in \mathbb{C}$), over $\mathbb{C}$, where all $x_i$ are zero except finitely many of them. Suppose a vector $(b_i)_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}$ is not the zero vector. Then $\{(b_{i+n})_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}|n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$ spans the space.

I have been trying to prove that the sequence consisting of all zeros and only one 1 in the $i$-th position, $e_i$, belongs to the above span. Then, the $e_i$ being a basis for the space proves my claim. I have been trying computations, but failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counterexample:** Take $b=e_0+e_1$. Let $S$ be the shift operator, so that $(S^nb)_k=b_{k-n}$. If shifts of $b$ would span the whole space, you will have
 $$e_0=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} a_n S^nb\qquad (1)$$
 with only finitely many $a_n$-s being nonzero. Let $n_{max}$ be the maximal $n$ with nonzero $a_n$, and $n_{min}$ --- the smallest $n$ with nonzero $a_n$.

I claim, that $n_{max}\leq -1$. Indeed, assume $n_{max}\geq 0$. Then $n_{max}+1$-st component of the rhs of (1) is $a_{n_{max}}+a_{n_{max}+1}=a_{n_{max}}$. But it has to be 0, since left hand side's only nonzero component is the 0'th one.

Similarly, you can show, that $n_{min}\geq 0$. Thus you would have $0\leq n_{min}\leq n_{max}\leq -1$. Contradiction.